# Use an Ajax script for a mail function

Tags: php, ajax, email

Can I use this part to send mails?

So if I add some php code in action.php, is this sufficient for a working email script (apart from the php code)?

This is the code, (and it's in a function don't worry this is not everything on the page)
And I know there is not a subject field, but I'll just enter the name (voornaam).

```
    var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
    var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
    var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    $.post('action.php',{action: "button", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
        $('#result').html(res);
    });
    document.getElementById('goed').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';
```

Comment: It already handles an insert query from action.php, the email part is a different bit of php code, can the ajax code handle two parts?

Comment: `action.php` can do anything you want it to do. You just need to code it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. The only information you really need to write an email is the receiver's address, everything else is content and a question of the a correctly setup email system. So yes, as long as your var email has a valid value, the server will have all the information it needs to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP support send mail function if the web server have correct setting,
try to research for this.
And you can use plugin like PHPmailer too.

The following is a simple example to send html email use mail function.
Just put the code into action.php will be OK.

```
<?php
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$subject = 'Sample mail';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";   

$content = '<html><header><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> </header><body>';
$content .= $voornaam;
$content .= $achternaam;
$content .= $telefoonnummer;
$content .= '</body></html>';

mail($email, $subject, $content, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that needs to be in the:  if($_POST['action'] == 'button'){} right?

Comment: Alright I tested it, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I need to add to the ajax code? I can't think of anything to add, because it should work.

Comment: It was something in my php.ini it's fixed now! Had to change the stmp.

Comment: congratulations. For more information, You can also try to use google stmp server instead of your own server. It can save time on server setting.